# Saved png is not as the Matlab figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm using the below code to save a png from a Matlab figure. But for some reason they are not the same. If anyone could please advise.

This is the code used:

```
fig1=figure('visible','off');
b = bar(bar_res);
x={'a' ;'b' ;'c'; 'd' ;'e'; 'f' ;'g'; 'h';...
     'i'; 'j' ;'k'; 'l'; 'm'; 'n' ;'o'; 'p' ;'q' ;'r'; 's';...
     't';'u'};
set(gca,'XTickLabel',x,'XTick',1:21);
rotateXLabels( gca, 90 );
with=char('Res with dash');
without=char('Res without dash');
legend('Reference',with,without,'Location','northwest');
set(gca,'FontSize',16);
y=ylabel('Number of trials','rot',90,'FontSize',18);
set(y,'Units','Normalized','Position',[-0.15, 0.5, 0]);
saveas(gca, 'a.png');
```

Matlab Fig appearing:

[image]

PNG saved:
[image]

Comment: The only, true,working asnwer is: Use `export_fig`. If you want Matlab to output good quality images, thats the only true options nowadays. hopefully Matlab will change their image saving code in the future (or incorporate export_fig to their software)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a submission on Matlab Central called [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig). It does exactly what you are looking for. From the description:

> This function saves a figure or single axes to one or more vector and/or bitmap file formats, and/or outputs a rasterized version to the workspace, with the following properties:Figure/axes reproduced as it appears on screen ,...

**Update**

The function accepts many parameters, where you have control over transparency, margins, and others. A series of usage examples can be found [here](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/blob/master/README.md). To simply export the current figure as a *.png* file:

```
export_fig test.png
```

Comment: so in my case it will be export_fig(gca, 'a.png'); ?

Comment: @sheperd I am currently (and successfully) using it on one of my functions the following way: export_fig('C:\path\filename\.png','-transparent','-m2','-painters'). If it works for you please let me know and I will update the answer!

Comment: Yes, it uses the current figure by default

Comment: it gave this error `Array dimensions must match for binary array op.

Error in export_fig (line 392)
                alpha = round(sum(B - A, 3)) / (255 * 3) + 1;`

Comment: You could try removing the -transparent, and if you do not have ghostscript installed, the painters. Try simply: export_fig test.png

Comment: it worked. Thank you. Would be able to use it to export .fig as well like this `export_fig test.fig`?

Comment: Use the '-nocrop' option. By default it crops the image to minimize the ammount of empty space. It doesn't support the .fig format

Comment: is it possible to save it with white background instead of gray?

Comment: This is another question altogether... But yes, before saving just set the background to white: set(gcf,'color','w');